# UITapGestureRecognizer Dismiss keyboard & UICollectionView conflict

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uicollectionview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a `UIScrollView` with numerous stack subviews.

I have a `UITapGestureRecognizer` that dismisses the keyboard and this works.

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissKbd))
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

One of my subviews is a stack view that holds a collection view.

```swift
stackView = UIStackView()
scrollView.addSubview(stackView)
stackView.axis = .horizontal
stackView.anchor(top: notesTextView.bottomAnchor, left: scrollView.leftAnchor, bottom: scrollView.bottomAnchor, right: scrollView.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 8, paddingLeft: 2, paddingBottom: 2, paddingRight: 2, height: 400)
let child = ImageGalleryViewController()
stackView.addArrangedSubview(child.view)
child.didMove(toParent: self)
```

Problem:

This results in:

1. Keyboard will dismiss when screen tapped
2. `didSelectItemAt` only works when two fingers are used on a cell

I assume this is to do with a conflict of gesture recognizers.

I would appreciate any guidance on how to make this work. I assume it's to do with the focus of the gesture recognizers?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can handle dismiss keyboard when scollView scrolled or offsetY is a constant number. you never need to dismiss the keyboard with gestures.